# How to wait until an async method finishes using Futures?

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit, concurrent.futures

I have an async Retrofit-based API call in Android and need to wait with the DB calls until the API call finishes, so that I am sure the proper data gets entered into the DB.

I read that you can use Futures to accomplish this task, however with my current implementation I get a null pointer exception.

Below is the API method:

```
public Future<Void> postPrintMode(String authorization, final int userid, String deviceuid, final Map payload){
    api.postPrintMode(authorization, userid, deviceuid, payload, new Callback<PrintMode>() {

        @Override
        public void success(PrintMode printMode, Response response) {

            if (printMode.get_id() != 0) {
                dbOps.writePrintMode(userid, printMode);
                bus.getBus().post(new EVTNewPrintMode(printMode));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            retrofitError.printStackTrace();
            APIUtils.showAPIResponseBody(retrofitError);
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

And here the block where I want to ensure that the async code is executed BEFORE I continue to read the DB results.

```
Future<Void> f = APIExec.getInstance().postPrintMode(IConstants.authorization, IConstants.userId, IConstants.deviceUid, payload);
    // here I get the null pointer exception
    f.get();
    // the code below needs to be executed after the postPrintMode(...) async method;
    DBPrintMode printMode = APIDBOps.getInstance().readPrintModeByPrintModeID(6);
    assertNotNull("Print Mode does not exist", printMode);
```

Comment: I don't think `Future` is what you want here. (you would need a synchronous call to retrofit inside a runnable for example). Your pattern would suit better a blockingqueue, a countdownlatch or possibly a semaphore

Comment: You are right, I used the CountDownLatch and stored globally the countdown signal and decrement it upon success or failure of the async method.

Comment: `stored globally the countdown signal` you can just declare it final in your method and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class that calls `public Future<Void> postPrintMode` method implement the `new Callback<PrintMode>` interface. After, you can your `postPrintMode` from it and pass a reference to itself into the method.

Here is a rough example (code not tested)

```
class Foo implements Callback<PrintMode> {

        Future<Void>  f;

        public Foo(){
            f = APIExec.getInstance().postPrintMode(IConstants.authorization, IConstants.userId, IConstants.deviceUid, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void success(PrintMode printMode, Response response) {

            if (printMode.get_id() != 0) {
                dbOps.writePrintMode(userid, printMode);
                bus.getBus().post(new EVTNewPrintMode(printMode));
            }
            if (f != null){
                f.get();
                // the code below needs to be executed after the postPrintMode(...) async method;
                DBPrintMode printMode = APIDBOps.getInstance().readPrintModeByPrintModeID(6);
                assertNotNull("Print Mode does not exist", printMode);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            retrofitError.printStackTrace();
            APIUtils.showAPIResponseBody(retrofitError);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a AsyncTaskThread class as below,

```
public class AsyncTaskThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Context context;
Handler myHandler;

public AsyncTaskThread( Context activityContext, Handler handler ) {
    this.context = activityContext;
    this.myHandler = handler;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // before starting thread you can pre process few things here if needed
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
```

//      do whatever you want to do here like calling your API and return your result
        return null;
    }

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // after doIn Background this method is called which will set the meesage object and give it back to handler
    Message message = new Message();
    message.obj = result;
    myHandler.sendMessage(message);
}
```

}

call this async class as,

```
new AsyncTaskThread(this, new MyHandler()).execute();
```

and You will have to put this handler class inside the class you are putting above line, depending upon the result you get in handle you can perform further operations,

```
    private class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would mean for each API call I need to write an extra async task, basically wrapping my async methods into async tasks. I do not want to alter my code base to such extend just for the purpose of being able to run unit tests. The sequential execution I need for the purpose of testing my existing code.

Comment: Well this won't be much of a change, as you just have to create a seprate async class, put the API call i doInBackground() method and then in handler you can proceed with the DB calls, anyways, choice is yours as I am not actually aware of the actual requirements

Comment: I have accomplished this challenge using the CountDownLatch and storing the signal globally. Once the async method completes I do: AppMemory.doneSignal.countDown(); and in case of success AppMemory.apiCallResult = true;